# Jasper report chart themes and configurations

Tags: java, jasper-reports, themes

I've been trying to format my graphs so that its labels do not have toothpick-sized widths and have better colouring and margins.

It turns out to be much harder and more tedious than I thought.

I've read [this page](http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/chart-customizers-1/) about writing your own class - Fine, but I want drag and drop for visual stuff.

I then looked at [this page](http://www.jaspersoft.com/ireport-and-jasperserver-creating-chart-themes-and-styles-tutorial), which gave a step-by-step instruction on how to use themes. It's neat, except my template inspector pops up blank and I can't find the place where I specified the class path to the bundle (I tried including the jar in my Netbeans project - no luck).

Anyway... is there any drag-and-drop support for chart and table customization in Jasper? Obviously, it's open source, so I can't expect the quality to approach that of MS Office, but so far, working with Jasper is like pulling teeth (not to mention the obscene amount of memory it uses even for tiny reports) and I'd gladly take any alternative packages if they exist.

Comment: Lol bro feeling ya, jasper reports are insane complicated and bad documentated.. 11 months and no answer. I need to apply a new theme too now. Told my boss it'll take 2 hours LOL gonna take me days as it seems..

Comment: Good luck Dan lol. I've already moved on from that job that needs Jasper Report (gosh time flies!). I hated that framework and can't imagine it's the gold standard for reporting. I hope your boss will be understanding. Personally, I got around Jasper Report by just writing an HTML/CSS reporting tool and fed the HTML to a PDF generator.

Comment: I hate it too, wasn't able to apply a new theme. I got a new job since then and I'm lucky I don't have to work with it anymore ;-)